# Create key array from duplicate value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array in the form:

```
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Asset',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Asset',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Periodic',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Periodic',
  },
```

and I would like to transform it into map (key, value) with as key the value is `itemFamily` so that it looks like this:

```
{ Asset:  
   [ { itemTitle: 'value example', 
       itemType: 'value example', 
       itemDescription: 'value example', 
       itemFamily: 'Asset' }, 
     { itemTitle: 'value example', 
       itemType: 'value example', 
       itemDescription: 'value example', 
       itemFamily: 'Asset' } ], 
  Periodic:  
   [ { itemTitle: 'value example', 
       itemType: 'value example', 
       itemDescription: 'value example', 
       itemFamily: 'Periodic' }, 
     { itemTitle: 'value example', 
       itemType: 'value example', 
       itemDescription: 'value example', 
       itemFamily: 'Periodic' } ] 
}
```

do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
yourArray.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
  if (!accumulator[element.itemFamily]) accumulator[element.itemFamily] = []
  accumulator[element.itemFamily].push(element)
  return accumulator
}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks but, I have a error message with my code.
```
const familyItems = categoryItems.reduce((acc, element) => {
        if (!acc[element.itemFamily]) acc[element.itemFamily] = []
        acc[element.itemFamily].push(element)
        return acc
    }, {})
```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.

Comment: @rmarquet21 that is a typescript error. You have to declare a type for the object passed as second argument of `reduce` (this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35859 could help, take a read).

Comment: Type is not declared automatically ? I don't find how to resolve this :(

Comment: Take a look on @captain-yossarian answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make illegal state unrepresentable.

It means that `Asset` property should contain only elements with `Asst` family. See `type Result`

```js
type Family = 'Asset' | 'Periodic';

interface Item {
  itemTitle: string,
  itemType: string,
  itemDescription: string,
  itemFamily: string,
}
const data: Item[] = [
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Asset',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Asset',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Periodic',
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'value example',
    itemType: 'value example',
    itemDescription: 'value example',
    itemFamily: 'Periodic',
  },
]

type Result = Record<string, Item[]>

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const handleProperty = (acc: Record<string, Item[]>, elem: Item) =>
  hasProperty(acc, elem.itemFamily) ? [...acc[elem.itemFamily], elem] : [elem]

const builder = (data: Item[]) =>
  data.reduce<Result>((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem.itemFamily]: handleProperty(acc, elem)
  }), {})

const result = builder(data)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgWwJYBsRQLxQOQEEDO+Ew2UAPjgAoQBOSA9gCZIDG2A3AFCdIB2wtAGZwW0AJICEUAN6coUJJIAqilBABcUfMDq8A5gBo5C5eA1adfQ8cUQEAEQj4WdMMAa9N23dfm2E8MhoXpb6RgC+nCz0vNpQjHDAcJoSdgDaALqYUGnGsvJ+yqrm2ABucCgArtAQAB6IYGrYRgUmdkpmmmUV1VB1DU0tBf6Ozq7uMV3lVTX1CI0QzcaFdoGoIF0ERCRD4UP5w0XAalM9swOLQysIHZCnM31zC0utI04uSG4e973984PLNoBRDrTaEYgvKB7PKA-wqY4laa-J4A16mO44JHnf6XWGSUYfL6TTFnR4XSHXNbBKi0BjMNi7fZ49rFH7Y55XIG3RGkv4c5kOd7jb4kh581GHVYg6nYah0JisSHQjLcUCQKAAJSclRQwGyWuiNEYAB5vFYDFBUghMgA+bjRWJ6gAWcHwlBo9EgNFA2WNAHkAEYAKwt7s9jwEvEY+AsPhtAAp6MHNIGQ1AwB6wJow2AAJTGTRJoMKGOpqAAMk1EENJpzFsqvAA1rx6AB3Xg2zB2+Sp6vAAB0GfowGHZn7LvwfvbOdooH7LAqKETwYtQ7zXCiMTiLqjahn3vQWHjIhYmgN9CNptChktkltFogagQKUkua7xgn+9Ax5YLAfT-7fwqRAN8AH4cn7SCTzSR87EAyRgIyf87CyTQYKfFVN0dKAA0qVBGFobJ4wSJIX3SDI3wwbt4kSOB+xoCBGEqURjS1fAdWABMfz-Pon0ozt4wOeRIP7E9OXQuCgOlEAMk0HdGD3TNZxAbjkIQfN5HCXMLWkLT7S3PUGPY3Vslw-DaGI2jcyAA)

Comment: Thanks ! but Asset and Periodic can still be other values that we do not know the goal is for it to be done dynamically without knowing the name of the key from the start

Answer (score 0):

A solution with reduce can be as follows:

```
let r3 = myArr.reduce((r, a) => {
    r[a.itemFamily] = [...(r[a.itemFamily] || []), a];
    return r;
  }, {});
```